# Wildcard SSL certificate with automatic subdomain forwarding

Tags: apache, ssl

I have a server where, as part of the service, users are given their own personalised subdomain, i.e. username.servicename.com. It's not particularly feasible to generate personalised vhost entries every time this happens, so I used a wildcard virtualhost file in Apache. This works great.

I'm now trying to get SSL working on it. I have a wildcard SSL certificate with a CommonName of *.servicename.com, so I think I'm doing what I should be doing. But... doesn't work. HTTP requests still work fine, HTTPS requests time out, and there's nothing in the logs. What is wrong with my config?

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php

    <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName servicename.com
        ServerAlias *.servicename.com #wildcard catch all
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
        UseCanonicalName Off
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
        ### Use mod_rewrite to direct servicename.com to www.
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^servicename.com
        RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
        ### Logging
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log_servicename combined

        <Directory /var/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName servicename.com
        ServerAlias *.servicename.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
        UseCanonicalName Off
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
        ### Use mod_rewrite to direct servicename.com to www.
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^servicename.com
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
        ### Logging
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log_servicename combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/servicename.com.certificate
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/servicename.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/rapidssl.intermediateca

        <Directory /var/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-ssl.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: more of a serverfault question

Comment: Does this at least work for `www` only (if you don't use `ServerAlias *.servicename.com` and just `ServerName www.servicename.com`)? (Just to check if the basics work.) (In addition, for security, disable SSLv2: `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2`.)